# Open tutorial on first run doesn't work properly

Tags: java, android

I have a tutorial in my app showing up when a user runs it for the first time

```
        Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() { 
             if (firstRun == true) {


                 Intent tut = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Tutorial.class);
                 startActivity(tut);
                 firstRun = false;

             }
         } 
    }, 200);
```

I have delayed it because without a delay i just get a black screen (the interface doesn't have the time to load)

But doing so i get the Tutorial.class opened many times, what am i doing wrong?

EDIT:

Here is some more code, i won't paste all of it since it would be only too long to read and   it wouldn't be relevant to the problem

I save my preferences like this

```
 @Override
protected void onStop(){
   super.onStop();

  // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
  // All objects are from android.context.Context
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putInt("Counter1", counter);
  editor.putInt("Counter2", counter2);
  editor.putBoolean("FirstRun", firstRun);
  editor.putString("Label1", label1S);
  editor.putString("Label2", label2S);

  editor.commit();
}
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
   editor.putInt("Counter1", counter);
   editor.putInt("Counter2", counter2);

   editor.commit();
 }
```

Here is how i restore them inside the onCreate();

```
// Restore previous settings and data


    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    int counterRestored = settings.getInt("Counter1", 0);
    int counter2Restored = settings.getInt("Counter2", 0);
    boolean firstRunRestored = settings.getBoolean("FirstRun", true);
    String label1Restored = settings.getString("Label1", "Counter 1");
    String label2Restored = settings.getString("Label2", "Counter 2");
    counter = counterRestored;
    counter2 = counter2Restored;
    firstRun = firstRunRestored;
    label1S = label1Restored;
    label2S = label2Restored;
    renameLabel();
    calculateTotal();
```

This is my second activity Tutorial.class

```
public class Tutorial extends MainActivity{

ImageButton  btnSkip, btnSkip2, btnNext, btnNext2;
RelativeLayout tutorial, tutPage1, tutPage2;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tutorial);


    btnSkip = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_skip);
    btnNext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
    btnSkip2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_skip2);
    btnNext2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_next2);
    tutorial = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.tutorial);
    tutPage1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.page1);
    tutPage2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.page2);


    btnSkip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    btnSkip2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            tutPage1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tutPage2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    btnNext2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            tutPage1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tutPage2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tutorial.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            finish();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Can we see the whole activity?  I don't see why you should need to use a delay or a handler for this.

Comment: why does Tutorial extends MainActivity? why not just Activity??

Comment: I think this is the problem.. you should make Tutorial extend Activity and don't forget the @Override annotation for onCreate()

Comment: Oh thanks :D it worked, i'll have to study about activities, because i don't understand why it was behaving like this. post it as answer so i'll mark it

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try

```
 if(firstRun){
     firstRun = false;
     Handler handler = new Handler(); 
     handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() { 
             Intent tut = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Tutorial.class);
             startActivity(tut);
         }
     } 
     }, 200);
 }
```

Comment: is this the only place where you start this activity?

Comment: Yes, it runs only once in the onCreate() after it checked the firstRun variable, also changing the delay number to higher doesn't help

Comment: have you thought of trying an asynktask where you put tha delay in doInBackground() and start your activity from postExecute()

Comment: Can you show me or point me to an example? 
Btw i found a partial solution, i had firstRun setup as static, now i removed it, now it doesn't loop anymore, but it runs 3 times

Comment: I edited my answer.. let's try this and if this doesn't work we'll try the asynktask, ok?

Comment: I was just trying the last code I suggested, the second activity is launched only once.. try debugging the app to see how your code is running

Answer (score 0):

The value of `firstRun` will not be stored persistantly over several runs.

You should store this value in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) so that it will retain its value even after the app has been closed.  You can find a tutorial on how to use SharedPreferences [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

Comment: i am storing it, i am saving it with a onStop(); 
But even if i wouldn't save it, the value would be stored until i would close my application